# How to calculate percentages with rounding

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def self.percent
  (Order.revenue.to_f / Order.goal.to_f) * 100.to_f
end
```

And the output is hideous:

> 0.47939999999999994% Funded

1. How can I make it so that it doesn't have the `0` in front i.e. `0.1..`, and only starts calculating at `1%`, `2%`, ...?
2. How do I get rid of the `0.43234324`? I'd like it to display nice round numbers i.e. `1%`, `2%`, and so on.

Comment: I'm guessing a simple to_i would do the trick?

Comment: Have you tried using `ceil` and `floor`? I've posted an answer below depicting how those functions would be invoked in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I think we can separate two answers here. First of all, you have to pay attention with rounding and truncating values. It could be dangerous in terms of inconsistent information. Anyways, based on your case, here it is.

- If you want to display only integers and ignore the decimal part of the number, you can use either [ceil](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Float.html#method-i-ceil) or [floor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Float.html#method-i-floor)

  ```
  0.47939999999999994.ceil 
  #=> 1

  0.47939999999999994.floor 
  #=> 0
  ```
- If you want to round your decimal, you can use [round](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Float.html#method-i-round) passing the precision desired:

  ```
  0.47939999999999994.round
  #=> 0

  0.47939999999999994.round(1)
  #=> 0.5

  0.47939999999999994.round(2) 
  #=> 0.48

  0.47939999999999994.round(3)
  #=> 0.479

  0.47939999999999994.round(4)
  #=> 0.4794
  ```

Your method should look like the following (using `round`)

```
def self.percent
  ((Order.revenue.to_f.round(2) / Order.goal.to_f.round(2)) * 100).round(2)
end
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, tried this but didn't work :  def self.percent
    (Order.revenue.to_f.round(2) / Order.goal.to_f.round(2)) * 100.round(2)
  end

Comment: You have to round the final result ! It would be something like: `((Order.revenue.to_f.round(2) / Order.goal.to_f.round(2)) * 100).round(2)`

Comment: How does `round` address the issue at hand without adding complexity? `ceil` is the most straightforward implementation.

Comment: Well, I think it is the most reliable way to do it, since it does not truncate or change the value, as I've pointed out. And, it turns out it solved our friend's problem, since he accepted the answer =P @zeantsoi

Comment: Fair enough, though I would contend that the OP accepted the less effective of the two answers.

Comment: Is it possible to round up from, 0.534324 to 1? if so how can this be achieved? thanks

Comment: Sure ! Just use `0.534324.round` =P

Answer (score 0):

It's not always necessary to round the number.  Often it's sufficient to simply output it with only the precision you want.  The method [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25), which is a thin wrapper around [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), works well for this.

Examples:

```
"%.0f" % 0.47939999999999994    # => "0"
```

The `"%.0f"` specification means to print a float point number with zero digits after the decimal point.

This method uses 5/4 rounding, which is fine for many applications.  Here we can see that the number is rounded up:

```
"%.0f" % 23.6    # => "24"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the difference between the original number/price and the new number /price. And divide it by the original number/ price to get the percentage:

```
def percentage_off
   (Float(original_price - our_price) / original_price * 100).ceil
end
```

the input example would now return `(1000 - 900) / 1000 * 100 = 10`