# Rounding up decimals in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code:

```
def self.percent
    ((Order.revenue.to_f.round(10) / Order.goal.to_f.round(10)) * 100).round(10)
 end
```

And the output is hideous:

```
0.67939999999999994% Funded
```

How can I make it so that it rounds up from 0.6342342 to 1%.

How do I get rid of the 0.43234324? I'd like it to display nice round numbers i.e. 1%, 2%, and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate percentages with rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257188/how-to-calculate-percentages-with-rounding)

Comment: 'erm the 10 is the number of places round, rounds to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round it thanks to the round() method:

```
irb(main):003:0> 0.6342342.round
=> 1
```

Comment: I'm using the round method, I guess I'm using it wrong? Please look at the above code, thanks so much

Comment: @SonnyBlack: You're writing `round(10)`, which means you want to round to 10 decimal places. You want `round(0)`, for zero decimal places. But zero is the default, so you can just write `.round` as shown in this answer.

Comment: You should remove the parameters that you are giving to its method: for instance, `round(1)` will approximate it to the first decimal, 2 to the second and son on. I think that you want to round it from 0... so `round(0)` or raw `round` should do the trick. Edit: @Chuck, you write faster than me ;)